# Swift pass data with segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tableview

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueDetail") {
        var detailViewController: DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController;
        var sweetIndex = tableView!.indexPathForSelectedRow().row
        var selectedSweet: AnyObject = self.timelineData[sweetIndex]
        var selectedUsers = selectedSweet["Sweeter"]
        detailViewController.selectedUser = selectedUsers as String
        println(detailViewController.selectedUser)

    }
}
```

I try to pass data from my `TimelineTableViewController` to `DetailViewController`, but I'm doing something wrong and I can't figure out what. Can someone help me or give me a better solution? I'm working with a `TableViewController`, a `TableViewCell` file and a `DetailViewController`. Thanks :)!

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint in order to verify that this block of code gets executed? Is there something printed on the console?

Comment: How do you know you're doing something wrong? Does this code not compile? Not run? Do something unexpected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segue is not executing your code because the segue identifier, specified in Interface Builder, for the desired segue is not "segueDetail".  Go into IB, select the segue, navigate to the 'Attributes Inspector' and assign (or fix) the identifier.